# Reading Projects Listing in CV

Tags: masters, cv, projects

So I'm a Physics undergrad about to apply for my master's. I'm currently making my CV and I was listing out the reading projects that I've done and was confused if I should:

List out all the books I used for the project

OR

Link in a website which has the books + all the resources (i.e. lectures and notes) I made for the project

Which is preferable and why?

## Clarifications

- **What is a reading project?** A project in which I undertake guided reading under a faculty. After reading certain sections we discuss the contents after which I'll be asked to deliver a short talk about it. I may or may not make notes dependent on time constraints.
- **Where am I applying?** I'm applying to universities in Germany for an MSc degree in Physics
- **What resources am I trying to list?** I'm trying to list the books/papers I used to study it. At the max, it has 4 entries.

Comment: Maybe an answer to your specific situation could depend on how long that list of resources is.

Comment: Could you please specify what's a reading project and which country you are applying? If I understand the meaning correctly, I'd consider highly unusual to list such thing in a CV, at least for my country.

Comment: Thank you! I've made edits, do let me know if there are any more clarifications

Comment: As a rule of thumb, don't rely on linking to things in a CV/research statement/other document. Inevitably, someone will print it out to read, and the link is then useless. Better just to explain in words where you can.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! Makes sense

Answer (score 2):

If I were looking at your CV in the US I would expect a line for each project, like

- supervised study of quantum electrodynamics

or

- reading project on quantum electrodynamics

I would not expect a list of sources any more than I would expect a list of texts for a course you took.

Comment: Understood, thank you!